# Remove backslash from json string in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have converted an object into string in wp8,by using
 `string str=JSONConvert.SerializeObject(object);`
Now I am getting a string like this:-
`{\"catGroup\":[{\"category\":{\"cgsId\":9,\"cgsName\":\"Ignition & Engine Filters\",\"values\":null}..`

I want to remove the backslash from the string.I have used
`str = str.Replace(@"\","");`

But still I am getting the string containing backslashes.
How to remove this?

Comment: Are you sure that the string actually contains those backslashes?That is how the string will be displayed in the inspector in the debugger, but the string does not actually have those backslashes, they are added by the inspector.

Comment: Yes, their is no change after using Replace method.The string remains unchanged.

Comment: I suspect the string remains unchanged because it doesn't contain any backslashes to begin with. As I said if you view the contents of a string variable in the debugger, the inspector will display the string as per your post, but it is just the debugger inspector that is adding them, they are not really part of the string.

Comment: Read Ben Robinson's remark again...

Comment: Yes in the debugger their is no slashes.But why is it appearing in the str.As I have to save this string in the database

Answer (score 1):

Those backslashes you see in your debug are not actually there. They are used as a escape character.

In c# the " indicates that you are talking about a string value. If you want a string to contain the " character you will have to type \" else you will close the string. If you don't know what I mean just try this

```
string wrong = "type a " in your string";
string correct = "type a \" in your string";
```

Since the debugger is working in the same way as your code compiler it has to add the \ to display a " character. Seeing your comments you want do write the string to a database, you can just do that straight away without worrying about the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
str.replaceall("\\"," ");
```